# ¿Cómo leer las propiedades de un PDF con C#?

Tags: c#, pdf

Escribo en esta oportunidad porque estoy trabajando con C# y necesito obtener las propiedades de un pdf, estas se anexan antes de escanearlo, que Liberia se puede utilizar? o cual sería la mejor manera de obtener esa información? [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

También me gustaría saber si se puede visualizar un listado de pdf que se encuentra en una carpeta, en forma tipo lista o en miniatura?

Answer (score 0):

La información que muestras en la imagen se conoce como metadatos, si estas usando .NET Framework puedes agregar una referencia a

> Shell32.dll

Asi:

1. Click derecho en el proyecto
2. Agregar referencia
3. Click en la pestaña COM
4. Seleccionas Microsoft Shell Controls and Automation
5. Click OK

Y hacer algo como esto:

```
List<string> arrHeaders = new List<string>();
List<Tuple<int, string, string>> attributes = new List<Tuple<int, string, string>>();

Shell32.Shell shell = new Shell32.Shell();
var strFileName = @"C:\Users\Admin\Google Drive\image.jpg";
Shell32.Folder objFolder = shell.NameSpace(System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(strFileName));
Shell32.FolderItem folderItem = objFolder.ParseName(System.IO.Path.GetFileName(strFileName));


    for (int i = 0; i < short.MaxValue; i++)
    {
        string header = objFolder.GetDetailsOf(null, i);
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(header))
            break;
        arrHeaders.Add(header);
    }

    // The attributes list below will contain a tuple with attribute index, name and value
    // Once you know the index of the attribute you want to get, 
    // you can get it directly without looping, like this:
    var Authors = objFolder.GetDetailsOf(folderItem, 20);

    for (int i = 0; i < arrHeaders.Count; i++)
    {
        var attrName = arrHeaders[i];
        var attrValue = objFolder.GetDetailsOf(folderItem, i);
        var attrIdx = i;

        attributes.Add(new Tuple<int, string, string>(attrIdx, attrName, attrValue));

        Debug.WriteLine("{0}\t{1}: {2}", i, attrName, attrValue);
    }
```

Comment: Gracias por responderme, siii eso es lo quiero hacer leer los metadatos de un pdf, voy revisar el codigo para probarlo, es la primera vez que trabajo con C# y no se mucho pero quisiera aprender